# Magento2 admin and frontend login is not working on localhost xampp server after installation

Tags: magento2, cookie-domain

I have installed Magento 2 latest version on my local xampp. Application is loading fine but the login on both frontend and backend is not working.

As per googling results I have made below changes,

1. Changing `localhost` into `127.0.0.1`
2. Changing `127.0.0.1` into `www.mysite-magento.com` by modifying the hosts file in `windows/system32` and `httpd.vhost.conf` on xampp server. Application loads as usual but login no luck.
3. Added `cookie_domain` in `core_config_data` table as `mysite-magento.com`
4. Changed `max_input_vars`, `max_input_time` and `max_execution_time` as `100000`, `600` and `3600` respectively.

When I try creating an account, the error message is showing as

> Invalid form key

When I try to login backend, no error message or log but login is not working.

These are the suggestions given in the forums None of them seems to be working. Any work around?

Answer (score 0):

Are you facing issues in the Backend or frontend login or both?

If its backend **Invalid form key**, then steps to reproduce

1: Unlock the Magento admin user, and run the command:

```
php bin/magento admin:user:unlock username
```

2: Run the cache command to clear the cache

3: If its localhost set the Base URL accordingly as http://localhost or http://127.0.0.1

4: Check if any external third-party extension that may create conflict after logging in. Please check the redirect URL if it's redirecting to any URL or check the logs when trying to log in.

5: You may be trying to reach the backend with the wrong URL. Check the correct URL for the admin panel through the following command:

```
php bin/magento info:adminuri
```

6: If possible, please share the URL of your application if all other pages, like category, are working.

Thnaks